# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string when attributes and parameters are the same data type

Tags: sql, report, datetime-format

I'm running a very simple query where I'm declaring an attribute (@BeginDate) and setting it to equal a report parameter (BeginDate). Both the attribute and the parameter have datetime data types

[Report Parameters Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdUFS.jpg)

DECLARE
@BeginDate datetime

SET @BeginDate='BeginDate'

SELECT *
FROM MessageDeliveries AS MD
WHERE MD.ProcessStart >='BeginDate';

When I run the report I receive the following error message: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any thoughts on how to correct this?

Comment: Which reporting tool and which brand of database engine are you using? Please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It's an SQL database. I figured out the solution to my issue. The:

```
SET @BeginDate='BeginDate'
```

clause was missing the `^`. It should be:

```
SET @BeginDate='^BeginDate^'
```

When I made that change the query worked.